# How to come back the original referer after multiple redirects to many domains

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

We have a platform which allows multiple users to create their websites at low budget. We are creating a feature where they can fetch latest posts from their social media account, which will demand authorization process.

Authorization process returns validation tokens that need to be stored in db and then start fetching the posts. Social Media App demands static call back url to handover the tokens. Since this is a platform, every user will have a different domain, so we ned to give a url from main domain of ours to capture the tokens for user. Once posts are fetched and stored, we finally need to take user to their domain so they can check if fetching posts worked fine. But the problem is that there are 3 domains in picture, so on the final page, we dont know from where the circle started.

So, we are facing the following scenario.

I have a **link A** of Domain 1.

It redirects to **link B** of Domain 1.

This redirects to a url **link C** of 3rd party API at Domain 2 which further redirects to another url **link D** of the same 3rd party API at Domain 2.

Then user gets redirected to a **link E** of Domain 3.

Now, I want to redirect back to **link A**.

How to achieve this?

**What I Tried**
I tried saving the **link A** in session when I was on Domain 1, but since three domains are in picture, I dont get session value in Domain 3. So I cannot redirect back to **link A** of Domain 1

Can you please suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: What is the point of this whole redirect circle?

Comment: @nice_dev I have explained the point in post description now. Please check.

Comment: I saw this on payment gateway, you should have control in link E for pointing to your end point. But in your example, thats to much redirect

Comment: ok, is Domain 1 and 3 under your control?

Comment: You can use database for this where Domain 1 and Domain3 refer to the same DB. As an alternative, you can also create API on Domain 1 and hit it from Domain 3 to check for status etc.